# How can i extract text from a PDF with python?

Tags: python, pdf

I'm looking to extract some text from a PDF. I'm using this code:

```
import PyPDF2
Doc = open('document.pdf','rb') 
pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(Doc)
pageObj = pdfreader.getPage(0)
pageObj.extractText()
```

Using this code the result from `pageObj.extractText()` is `''`. I don't know why this happen because there are text in the pdf that is open. This document just have 1 page.

Someone know what happen? or if there is another way to get information from a PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can try with PDF Plumber.

Instead of printing you can write it in a text file.

```
import pdfplumber
with pdfplumber.open(r'D:\document.pdf') as pdf:
    first_page = pdf.pages[0]
    print(first_page.extract_text())
```

Comment: Thank! it work perfectly!